# YGuard Obfuscate failing with message : yGuard detected a duplicate class definition for javax.xml.bind.ModuleUtil

Tags: java, obfuscation, yguard

My pom has

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

and I can see in `jaxb-api` there are two classes with same name. One from `javax/xml/bind/ModuleUtil` and other from `META-INF/versions/9/javax/xml/bind/ModuleUtil`.

How do I exclude this while obfuscating? Any idea?

```
yGuard detected a duplicate class definition for 
    javax.xml.bind.ModuleUtil
    [jar:C:\Users\Test\IdeaProjects\**\target\Test.jar|javax/xml/bind/ModuleUtil.class] in 
    [jar:C:\Users\Test\IdeaProjects\**\target\Test.jar|META-INF/versions/9/javax/xml/bind/ModuleUtil.class]
```